# git fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: git, github

I tried to contribute to Bioconda. However, I got the following error:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mictadlo/bioconda-recipes.git
Cloning into 'bioconda-recipes'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 312339, done.
remote: Total 312339 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 312339
Receiving objects: 100% (312339/312339), 332.37 MiB | 9.93 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (172897/172897), done.
Updating files: 100% (18842/18842), done.

$ cd bioconda-recipes/
$ git remote add upstream https://ghp_eWgtJStONjyA40srOLuSCnEQ0rrdza@github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes.git
$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'

$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': mictadlo
Password for 'https://mictadlo@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/mictadlo/bioconda-recipes.git/'
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled 2FA for your Github account? If so, you cannot use your password with HTTPS URLs anymore. See [Using two-factor authentication with the command line](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication#using-two-factor-authentication-with-the-command-line)

Comment: I updated my question and it includes Token in command but I still have problems

Comment: In Yuor new edit, you are adding a token to the upstream remote, but are pushing to the origin remote. The token would need to be used there (origin).

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

Double-check the "password" you have entered when trying to push back to your own repository.

[Since Aug. 2021](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/), you would need to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/set-up-git#next-steps-authenticating-with-github-from-git).

You can also, for testing, try with an SSH URL, provided you have [registered a public SSH key to your profile](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

Comment: I updated my question and it includes Token in command but I still have problems

Comment: @user977828 Yes, I was following your edits in real time, and left a comment.

Answer (score -2):

For pushing code into the repo, you need to add an SSH key to your GitHub.

Follow this link for more information:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: I updated my question and it includes Token in command but I still have problems